# Trying to build project after adding values-21 folder and it's showing error

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-resources

:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
C:\Users\abc\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\src\main\res\values-21
Error:Error: Invalid resource directory name
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> C:\Users\abc\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\src\main\res\values-21: Error: Invalid resource directory name

Answer (score 27):

Please change Folder name `values-21` to `values-v21`.